# Sharing an object from global vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I would like to share a common url between different components in vuejs
So in my main.js

```
Vue.prototype.$apiurl = '127.0.0.1:8000/api'
```

Now in my component i would like to call

```
console.log("apiurl is", this.$apiurl );
```

The above doesnt work. How do access global variables in vuejs

Answer (score 0):

Having a dictionary for keeping constants seems more appropriate to me in this case, something like this:

```
APP_CONSTS = {
  API_URL: "127.0.0.1:8000/api"
}
```

Then accessing it whenever you need, like `APP_CONSTS.API_URL`.

In some situations you may need to share data between components, in these cases [state management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) comes into play. But it may be an overkill for your case.

Comment: the APP_CONSTS where do i place it. On the main root?

Comment: When i place it in the main root js whenever i try calling it via App_CONST.API_URL am getting an error APP_CONSTS is not defined

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI it depends on your app structure. You can put it in a separate JS file and include it before including VueJS, that will make sure it will be available.